# Adding MKMapView Dynamically to the UIView

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I am trying to add a MKMapView dynamically to the UIView. I have the following code:

```
 self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.contentView.frame)];
```

The above does not completely fill the UIView with the MKMapView but the following works perfectly.

```
self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: I want to know why the first statement does not completely fill the UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the value of `self.contentView.frame.origin`? Chances are it is not (0,0), unless contentView itself is at the upper-left corner of its superview.

You should probably use `self.contentView.bounds` instead, anyway.